# Google Chrome extension to send a web page as PDF through Gmail

Tags: chrome

I am looking for a Google Chrome extension that can send a page as PDF through Gmail (e.g. by a simple click on the extension icon at the right of the address bar, or right clicking on the page). I don't want to manually have to save the page as PDF then attach it in an e-mail.

The extension [Send from Gmail](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/send-from-gmail-by-google/pgphcomnlaojlmmcjmiddhdapjpbgeoc) is almost perfect but it does not attach the page as PDF.

[image]

I use Google Chrome on Windows 7.

Comment: If anyone has any idea please add an answer.

Comment: I haven't found anything so far.